# Why no caching of the OPTIONS call?

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to make an OPTIONS call cached but when looking at http.js for angular I found this:

```
if ((config.cache || defaults.cache) && config.cache !== false &&
    (config.method === 'GET' || config.method === 'JSONP')) {
  cache = isObject(config.cache) ? config.cache
  : isObject(defaults.cache) ? defaults.cache
  : defaultCache;
}
```

Is there a reason why it's set to only cache GET and JSONP? In my case I want to fetch the data types tied to a REST endpoint and that's typically something I'd like to cache. Is there a specific reason for not making this cacheable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10961) and it seems likt it'll be changed in the future.